# Using a for loop with ggplot2 to plot multiple graphs within a data frame

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, ggplot2

Was just wondering if somebody could help with a problem I am having in R with a for loop using ggplot2. I have carried out some clustering to find patterns of data that change over time. There are various patterns in total with 38 graphs of patterns. The output of the clustering is to put side by side all 38 graphs which is nice for visualisation.

But I want to zoom in to individual graphs to zoom in to them for presentation and a cleared view of a pattern. This is easy manually, however, writing 38 versions of the same script but just with a different cluster in each one is very tedious, so I would like to create a for loop in order to achieve in one chunk of quick code. I have done this code (with some help online also), however, I am unable to get the ouput of the individual 38 graphs. the code itself works as I can specify one cluster which will then give me an output of that specific cluster, but I want to create a code that will creat all 38 different clusters.

The code I am using is as follows:

The data frame is called dfllgc, within which dfllgc$cluster contains information on the individual clusters. The for loop I am attempting is as follows but does not work. Any help would really really be appreciated!

```
    for(cluster in dfllgc$cluster){
  df<-subset(dataframAMIRllgc,cluster == 1:38)
  df$Time_point<-factor(df.s$Time_point, levels = c("p3", "p15", "p30","p60"))
  g<-ggplot(df, aes(x=Time_point, y=abundance, group=llgc, colour=llgc))+
  geom_line(size=1.5)+
  geom_point(size=4)+
  ggtitle("Cluster 29: Patterns over time (5 genes) \n") +
  xlab("\nAge") + ylab("Expression(CPM)\n")
  print(g) }
```

Changing  df<-subset(dataframAMIRllgc,cluster == 1:38) to == 1, or 15 etc, or any other cluster does indeed produce that one cluster, but not all 38 with 1:38.

Finally, with the title (ggtitle), is there a way to automate also the titles such that I can have a template, but that the cluster number as well as number of genes are automatically applied to the correct clusters?

Thank you so much! Any help would be much appreciated :)

example data

```
    merge   cluster Time_point  llgc    abundance
1   High[26-50%]p15 1   p15 High[26-50%]    166.5400335
38  High[26-50%]p3  1   p3  High[26-50%]    255.5007952
75  High[26-50%]p30 1   p30 High[26-50%]    122.1110473
112 High[26-50%]p60 1   p60 High[26-50%]    78.84340532
149 Low[0-10%]p15   1   p15 Low[0-10%]  86.40962037
186 Low[0-10%]p3    1   p3  Low[0-10%]  205.9750297
223 Low[0-10%]p30   1   p30 Low[0-10%]  60.23843127
260 Low[0-10%]p60   1   p60 Low[0-10%]  56.64259547
297 Medium[11-25%]p15   1   p15 Medium[11-25%]  165.2372227
334 Medium[11-25%]p3    1   p3  Medium[11-25%]  223.3891249
371 Medium[11-25%]p30   1   p30 Medium[11-25%]  155.1325448
408 Medium[11-25%]p60   1   p60 Medium[11-25%]  176.8285175
2   High[26-50%]p15 2   p15 High[26-50%]    85.21789981
39  High[26-50%]p3  2   p3  High[26-50%]    211.5359752
76  High[26-50%]p30 2   p30 High[26-50%]    35.7475454
113 High[26-50%]p60 2   p60 High[26-50%]    12.87995477
150 Low[0-10%]p15   2   p15 Low[0-10%]  77.20608808
187 Low[0-10%]p3    2   p3  Low[0-10%]  43.04550979
224 Low[0-10%]p30   2   p30 Low[0-10%]  34.88976766
261 Low[0-10%]p60   2   p60 Low[0-10%]  9.791146582
298 Medium[11-25%]p15   2   p15 Medium[11-25%]  46.21377697
335 Medium[11-25%]p3    2   p3  Medium[11-25%]  34.89603178
372 Medium[11-25%]p30   2   p30 Medium[11-25%]  14.18668175
409 Medium[11-25%]p60   2   p60 Medium[11-25%]  7.360330065
3   High[26-50%]p15 3   p15 High[26-50%]    47.75793997
40  High[26-50%]p3  3   p3  High[26-50%]    62.3529071
77  High[26-50%]p30 3   p30 High[26-50%]    17.8348889
114 High[26-50%]p60 3   p60 High[26-50%]    14.26366778
151 Low[0-10%]p15   3   p15 Low[0-10%]  138.1451371
188 Low[0-10%]p3    3   p3  Low[0-10%]  185.1184602
225 Low[0-10%]p30   3   p30 Low[0-10%]  63.52332626
262 Low[0-10%]p60   3   p60 Low[0-10%]  39.40566363
299 Medium[11-25%]p15   3   p15 Medium[11-25%]  26.32551336
336 Medium[11-25%]p3    3   p3  Medium[11-25%]  49.72067928
373 Medium[11-25%]p30   3   p30 Medium[11-25%]  8.288553629
410 Medium[11-25%]p60   3   p60 Medium[11-25%]  5.385031193
```

Comment: You might be able to use `cluster` column as a grouping variable that will be used to produce different plots automatically. Something like this: https://www3.nd.edu/~steve/computing_with_data/13_Facets/facets.html . But we need to have some of your data in order to help you. Maybe a sample from 2-3 different clusters.

Comment: Put in a `ggsave` call at the end of your loop, something like `ggsave(plot = g, file = paste0("plot_", cluster, ".png"))`. You can use `paste` also to build whatever title string you want.

Comment: hi all! Many thanks! have tried faceting to no avail, as well as ggsave. nothing happens . I suspect the for loop doesnt like the df<-subset(dataframAMIRllgc,cluster == 1:38). I have attached to the original post some sample data. The clusters plot as abundance on the y axis with time on the x axis. If i can get the for loop to create all 3 automarically as well as title them appropriately automaticaly to enter the amount of genes present and the cluster number that would be perfect! many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I 100% understand what you are trying to do but I think there is a problem with your subset and then you need to add a save function to the end.  Hopefully this does what you want:

```
dfllgc$Time_point<-factor(dfllgc$Time_point, levels = c("p3", "p15", "p30","p60"))

for(cluster in unique(dfllgc$cluster)) {

    g<-ggplot( dfllgc[ dfllgc$cluster == cluster, ], 
              aes(x=Time_point, y=abundance, group=llgc, colour=llgc)) +
        geom_line(size=1.5) +
        geom_point(size=4) +
        ggtitle( paste0("Cluster ", cluster,": Patterns over time (5 genes)") ) +
        xlab("Age") + ylab("Expression(CPM)")

    ggsave(paste0("Cluster_", cluster,".png"), g) 

}
```

Changes made:

- removed the subset line and added the cluster subset/filter to `ggplot` line but it could just as easily be separate.
- moved the `factor` conversion outside the for loop so it only needs to be applied once.
- set the title and file name to change with each cluster

Comment: Amazing!!! Thank you so much! and yes, this has absolutely solved the problem! including removing ggsave and having the output in R!  Quick question, is there a function similar to your "cluster_" solution, to adding the number of genes per cluster as this differs also? would it be paste0("_ genes")?

Comment: That depends where the gene information is coming from. I couldn't see anything that looked like a number of genes in the table you provided but I don't really know what I'm looking at.  

If it was in the table and all items in the cluster had the same number of genes then you could do something like: 

`gene_no <- dfllgc[ dfllgc$cluster == cluster, ]$genes[1]` to select the number of genes an add this to `paste0("Cluster ", cluster, ": Patterns over time (", gene_no, " genes)")`.

If you add it to your data I'll update my answer.

Comment: So sorry for the delay in replying, but thank you for the reply! will play around and try this out and let you know how it goes! And yes, correct, there is no separate information regarding the specific amount of genes per cluster apart from those genes that simply belong to one specific cluster.. Will try this out and get back to you. Again, many thanks for your help!

Comment: no luck unfortunately, I can't get the right call from the data (as in number of genes). In theory, if I add the amount of genes that belong to cluster 1 and then vectorise this, I shold be use the paste0 function to call the right values per cluster...

Comment: If you have a data.frame that has the cluster id and the number of genes then you could either merge it will the main data.frame or just look it up directly.  If your number of genes table was: `noGenes <- data.frame(clusterNo = c(1,2,3), genes = c(5,7,3)`. Then you could use:
`paste0("Cluster ", cluster, ": Patterns over time (", noGenes[clusterNo==cluster,"genes"], " genes)")` to look it up directly.    If you post your number of genes dataset then I might be able to give a more conclusive (and tested) answer.

Comment: ok cool, I will give this a go and see how it goes. Actually, yes apologies for the vague part about the actual number of genes. In the table on my original post, the number of genes is simply the number of rows that belong to the a specific cluster type. So if you look at all rows that have cluster 1 in them, there are 12 rows... and so on and so forth. So there are 12 gene in cluster 1 etc...

Comment: That should be possible.  I haven't tested but try this: `paste0("Cluster ", cluster, ": Patterns over time (", sum(dfllgc$cluster==cluster), " genes)")`

Comment: Apologies for getting back late. Works perfectly! Two methods work perfectly: sum(dfllgc$cluster==cluster) and ggtitle( paste0("Cluster ", cluster,": Patterns of gene expression over time (", dataframe$n_genes[dfllgc$cluster == cluster], " genes)")) + xlab("Age") + ylab("Expression(CPM)")... by adding a column to add the number of genes per cluster... Thank you so so much for all of your help! Just new to for loops and automation and having a lot of fun learning this all! Thank you for all of your help

Comment: That's great!  Don't forget to accept and up vote the answer if it works for you, thanks!